# org-journal: How to add new entry at current time?

Tags: org-mode

I'm playing with org mode and org-journal for the first time. My basic entry looks like

```
* Wednesday, 02/24/2016
** 15:02 Blah blah blah

notes written here.
```

I would now like to append something to today's entry so that I get something like

```
** 15:37 A new entry

Here we go...
```

I can't find any way to do this via a key binding. Of course, I could enter the new time manually, but I don't want to do that. Is there some way to do this?

Edit: I have tried C-u C-j, which does indeed open the current day's journal with a new time entry, but this journal cuts opens on a second window

[image: Before C-u C-j]

[image: After C-u C-j]

I'm not sure which version of org-mode I'm using, but it's probably the latest, since I installed it a couple of days ago.

Comment: I have edited the post with more details.

Answer (score 2):

By default, org-journal uses a second window:

```
(defcustom org-journal-find-file 'find-file-other-window
  "The function to use when opening an entry. Set this to `find-file` if you don't want org-journal to split your window."
  :type 'function :group 'org-journal)
```

Try setting that variable to `find-file`:

```
(setq org-journal-find-file #'find-file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use to add journal entries:

```
(defun journal-new-entry ()
  "Add new entry to journal.
Add new day if necessary, otherwise, add to current day."
  (interactive)
  (find-file "~/Dropbox/org-mode/journal.org")
  (let* ((date (calendar-current-date))
     (year (elt date 2))
     (month (elt date 0))
     (day (elt date 1)))
    (org-datetree-find-date-create (list month day year)))
  (save-restriction
    (org-narrow-to-subtree)
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert (format "\n**** %s" (format-time-string "%H:%m"))))
```

It is obviously specific to my journal file, but is otherwise pretty generic to org.

Answer (score 0):

As I recommended before, try:

```
C-c C-j
```

to add new journal entries in the same window. `C-u C-j` is different. The manual shows these two key bindings:

```
To create a new journal entry: C-c C-j
To open today’s journal without creating a new entry: C-u C-c C-j
```

To find the version of orgmode:

```
M-x org-version
```

Comment: This sort of works. But for some reason it opens a window, so I'm left with two windows containing the same journal buffer...